# In PHP Ajax post, how to get array responses to multiple html elements with a single ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

View page

```
<button id = 'compare_button'>Compare</button>
<div id="sourceResponse"></div> 
<div id="destResponse"></div>   
<div id="missingResponse"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#compare_button').click(function(event){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'compare.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(response){       
        ...
        $("#sourceResponse").html(some-response); 
        $("#destResponse").html(some-response);  
        $("#missingResponse").html(some-response); 
    });
});
```

Compare.php

```
....
//converting arrays to json
echo json_encode($source_files);
echo json_encode($dest_files);
echo json_encode($missing_files);
```

How do I handle the json response above in order to display respective data in these 3 html elements?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at the code yourself, and then we help you when you get stuck. Why don't you show us what you've tried (even if it isn't working) in order to solve this issue?

Comment: $source_files , $dest_files, $missing_files are large arrays that contain thousands of elements each element being the file path.

Comment: create an object with 3 properties, and store your arrays in to it, and then do `echo json_encode($yourObject);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an array that includes your responses, `json_encode` it and return it in the response

```
$output = array(
    'source'  => $source_files,
    'dest'    => $dest_files,
    'missing' => $missing_files
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

in your javascript, use it like this:

```
.done(function(response){       
    ...
    $("#sourceResponse").html(response.source); 
    $("#destResponse").html(response.dest);  
    $("#missingResponse").html(response.missing); 
});
```

---

EDIT:
In your `done` handler

```
// replace this
// $("#sourceResponse").html(response.source);

// with the following
$.each(response.source, function(key,value) {
    console.log(key+"-"+value); // use this to check the object

    // assuming the text you want is directly in the value you can use this
    $("#sourceResponse").append('<code>'+value+'</code></br>');
})
```

Basically we are iterating over the `response.source` object members and constructing the `<code>string</code></br>` and appending them to the `div` instead of pushing the contents of the objects straight through.

Comment: Thanks. Can we store each response into arrays and display the elements using foreach loop in the view page?

Comment: I want to do something like this -  `foreach ($response_source as $key => $value){ ?>
   <code><?php echo $key ." ". $value; ?></code><br>`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, if you can share some context code I might be able to help. The code in your comment should work provided you close the bracket that you opened at the `foreach`

Comment: I want the html output to be in this form `<div id="sourceResponse"><code>test1</code><br><code>test1</code><br>...</div>` . How can we do this?

Comment: are the values "test1" contained in the initial `$source_files` array? can you please edit your question to include a small sample of each array. I think I understand what you need but samples always help :)

Comment: Yes, in compare.php  `$source_files = array(test1,test2, test3...);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92508/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-subhas-takhellambam).

Answer (score 0):

this is the shortest way:

```
echo json_encode([
    "sourcefiles" => $source_files,
    "destfiles" => $dest_files,
    "missingfiles" => $missing_files
]);

console.log(response.sourceFiles);
console.log(response.destFiles);
console.log(response.missingFiles);
```